# Adding Youtube thumbnail on UICollectionView in swift

Tags: swift, youtube, uicollectionview, thumbnails, youtube-data-api

I am trying to find a way to add a collection of youtube video thumbnails on a `UICollectionView`. But in the way how I am trying the thumbnail (image) is not being showed, and also I have not figure out a way to add a collection (array) of URL's on `NSData`.

Or if there are other ways to do so like with Youtube API.

And just to mention that I do not know Obj-C so any code in Obj-C wouldn't be very helpful.

Here is my code

```
var videoName:[String] = ["First Video", "Second Video", "Third Video"]
var videoImage:[String] = ["thumbnail1","thumbnail2","thumbnail3"]

let thumbnail1 = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGF6bOi1NfA/0.jpg")
let thumbnail2 = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y71r1jhMdRk/0.jpg")
let thumbnail3 = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfsRZsvraD8/0.jpg")

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: SongCollectionView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SongCollectionView

    cell.labelCell.text = videoName[indexPath.row]
    let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: /*videoImage[indexPath.row]*/ thumbnail1!) // in the commented section I am trying to add an array of strings which contains thumbnail URL's
    cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sGF6bOi1NfA/0.jpg` redirects to the video, and does not display a thumbnail image.  Are you sure you're using the right URL?

Comment: yes u are right such a stupid mistake thnx

Comment: What is the right URL please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using tuplets rather than two separate arrays

```
let videoData = [("First Video", "sGF6bOi1NfA/0"), ("Second Video","y71r1jhMdRk/0"), ("Third Video", "qfsRZsvraD8/0")]

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell: SongCollectionView = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SongCollectionView
  let (name, token) = videoData[indexPath.row]

  cell.labelCell.text = name
  let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=\(token).jpg")!)
  cell.imageCell.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
  return cell
}
```

Comment: Jut to ask u another additional question. Is there a better way to do so (for example not adding video ID's manually, or take the name of the videos etc) ?

Comment: it depends on what you are going to accomplish. For example you could also create a struct containing name and token properties and add, update or remove instances in an mutable array